# Displaying News Teasers in Storyblok with getStaticProps. And only call API when the block "NewsOverview" is in use

Tags: next.js, storyblok

I have created some News-pages in the "News" folder. I want to tease the news on the home and on some other pages. So i have already achieved to get all news in the getStaticProps. But know i want to only call the storyblok API when the Block "NewsTease" is in use. Can anyone help me around with this?

The best solution would be to directly send this data not via `<StoryblokComponent>` else directly to the `<NewsOverview>` component.

This is my Query so far:
`const { data: newsOverview } = await storyblokApi.get(`cdn/stories`, { ...sbParams, content_type: "news", excluding_fields: "body",  });`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your next.js page structure looks like, but the easiest solution would be to create a seperate file for the page where `NewsTeaser` is in use. If you fetch the data in there, it will only be loaded on this page.

You could then use [React Context](https://react.dev/learn/passing-data-deeply-with-context) to pass down the `newsOverview` data directly to your component.

However, if you don't know beforehand, where the `NewsTeaser` component will be used, you can fetch the data inside your component, usually on the client-side with `useEffect` or a libary like [Tanstack Query](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/overview).